# Insert new row and move data based on cell text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to automate a Google sheet to save time for a team member. I have zero scripting experience. I am trying to insert a row based on a "Yes" result from column K in a Google form submission sheet and then move data in cells L:P to the new row, all without messing up the query functions that are pulling this data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

## Appending selected data from a form submission

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name')
  if(e.values[11]=="Yes") {
    var nV=e.values.slice(11,16);
    ss.appendRow(nV);
  }
}
```

> Since you said that you have zero scripting experience, I should warn you that you cannot run this function without supplying the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) and personally I would never append new rows to a linked sheet.  I would append the rows to another sheet instead.  There have been problems with the onFormSubmit trigger lately which causes spurious additional triggers as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54860085/7215091).