# Sending automated E-Mail when a Cell is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Initial situation:
I am trying to send an automated Mail to the supervisor, when someone of his team submitted a holiday application, so the supervisor is able to approve it.

The application is submitted via a form and the form answers are moved to a spreadsheet. 
The form answers contain: email address & Team. 
There are three teams, each with one supervisor.

The plan is to send a mail with an automated text like: 
"One of your team members submitted a holiday application"

The mail should be send the moment the form answer is moved to the spreadsheet.

Comment: i am using a google form, which is connected with a spreadsheet. 
The answers are moved automaticly

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//You create a form submit trigger
function myFunction(e) {
  var recipient=e.namedValues('email address');
  var subject="Holiday Application"
  var body=Utilities.formatString('One of your team members in %s submitted a holiday application.',e.namedValues('Team')); 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

If you have problems with multiple trigger see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t).