# Why does google app script trigger send duplicate emails?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an appscript that triggers an email to certain users on form submission. The trigger works fine, except, it is sending out duplicate emails to the users.

I have tried adding a column to my underlying google sheet to mark if an email was sent and if it was sent, do not send another email. It did not work. There is a lot more code, but, I have included the relevant piece.

```
  var _sheet = sheet;
  var _data = getRowsData(_sheet);

  var _markPending = function(d) {

    d.state = PENDING_STATE;
    d.identifier = Utils.generateUUID();
    d.budgeted = FIN_BUDGET;
    d.DepartmentName = FIN_SUB;
    d.financeDirectorApproval = FIN_APPROVE;
    d.finalFinanceApproval = CFO_STATE;

 Logger.log(_markPending);
   manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME].match(EMAIL_REGEX);

   d.manager_email = manager_email


     if (d.mailSent != 'Sent') 
    {
    MailApp.sendEmail(SETTINGS.HR_MANAGER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, subject2, "",{ htmlBody: message});
     d.mailSent = MAIL_SENT;
   };
```

```
Head    onFormSubmit    Trigger May 21, 2019, 9:57:39 AM    3.141 s 
Completed
Head    onFormSubmit    Trigger May 21, 2019, 9:57:39 AM    3.298 s 
Completed
```

````
  Logger.log("Good afternoon, Good Evening and Good night");
  var sheet = getSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(RESPONSES_SHEET);
  handler = SheetHandler(sheet);
  handler.processSheet();
  writeToLog();
  var lastRowValues = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var Var1 = lastRowValues[0][1];
  var Var2 = lastRowValues[0][13];
  var Var3 = lastRowValues[0][17];
  var Var4 = lastRowValues[0][16];
  var Var5 = lastRowValues[0][2];
  var Var6 = lastRowValues[0][7];
  var Var7 = lastRowValues[0][8];
  var Var8 = lastRowValues[0][3];
  var Var9 = lastRowValues[0][5];  
  var Var10 = lastRowValues[0][27];

  var subject2 = "Form Input - " + Var1 + " - " + Var2
  var manager_email = "abc@abc.com";

  var emailBody = "Labe1: " + Var1 
  + "<br /> \ Label2: " + Var2 
  + "<br /> \ Label3: " + Var3 
  + "<br /> \ Label4: " + Var4 
  + "<br /> \ Label5: " + Var5 
  + "<br /> \ Label6: " + Var6  
  + "<br /> \ Label7: " + Var7 
  + "<br /> \ Label8: " + Var8 
  + "<br /> \ Label9: " + Var9;


    MailApp.sendEmail(manager_email, subject2, "",{ htmlBody: emailBody });

//    } ;      
//  
}; ```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I be getting multiple unwanted event blocks from the same onFormSubmit Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you getting unwanted triggers see this:[How can I be getting multiple unwanted event blocks from the same onFormSubmit Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t).

You may be able to use something similar to that logic example to eliminated the unwanted triggers

Comment: Thanks! Updated my original question with the formsubmit code. I am not a programmer by any stretch of the imagination. I am assuming I have to tweak my formsubmit code to incorporate the changes you refer to. Please advise.

Comment: @PushkarWazat Yes I just got through adding a form so that people can contact me directly from this site and this is what I put into the code. `if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2] && e.values[3] && e.values[4] && quota>0) {`  All questions are required.  The first time I ran the code it ran twice but I only received one email because the second one had no questions answered.