# Triggers start randomly on google apps scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have activated a onFormSubmit trigger on my spreadsheet, it starts randomly sometimes (no form submited)

My program fills a pdf, then send it.

[image: Responses file]

[image: Trigger]

Comment: Try to add some code to your question, Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Content on this site should be in English even the screenshots. If it's too much work to get them in English or not possible at all, then a translation of the most relevant parts should be included. By the way we also have [es.so]. By the other hand, in this case, the screenshots doesn't look to be helpful to understand what is happening. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard this happening without a normal trigger first but I have detect spurious after triggers with the onFormSubmit Trigger.  At any rate, take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t).  I suspect that you can use the same tactic to inhibiting any unwanted triggers.