# onFormSubmit Trigger occurs twice randomly about every few weeks

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

Firstly, I want to say that this issue is different from all previous Form Submit Trigger errors with Google Apps script. This one triggers twice, while still having access to all form submit info of the previous form submission and triggers the program again.

Furthermore, the additional form submit trigger glitch does not add a row to the spreadsheet form responses, this is because the user isn't submitting the form twice, it's on Google for triggering it. This has happened randomly about 3 times in the past few months and it is extremely critical that my program only executes once for each job. After hours of research, I was unable to find a problem similar to mine. The problem also persisted even after adding the following line of code:

> if(e.values && !e.values[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHpt9.png)){return;} //To fix error when onFormSubmit
>   triggers multiple times under one form submission //Doesn't work/do
>   anything 6/8/2020

[image]

[image]

Comment: A similar behaviour was reported few months ago in Issue Tracker (see [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144110219), [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144219397) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151898)), but it supposedly got fixed on Nov 19. If your trigger or your project were created before that date, you might be experiencing that. If that's not the case, I'd consider reporting this in Issue Tracker.

Comment: @Rubén No, as I stated above, this pertains to a different problem and I stated above that the line of code shown there does not work

Comment: Thank you very much @Iamblichus , I will look into it and update the trigger on my project.

Comment: I do not think updating the trigger solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

This behaviour was very recently reported on Issue Tracker, probably by the OP:

- [#158892709: onFormSubmit Trigger occurs twice randomly about every few weeks for one form submission](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158892709)

Anyone who might be experiencing this can click the star on the top left in order to subscribe to it and also to prioritize it.