# Google Form submits similar previous Form Submissions upon 1 submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Yesterday, my Google Form/Spreadsheet registered 2 additional form submissions upon 1 Form Submission. Were these 2 additional form submissions perfect duplicates of the first one? Nope. This is even weirder. After the first one, another form submission with the same name and email of the first one came in shortly seconds after that was a duplicate of a PREVIOUS one (months back). The same happened for the second additional form submission.

[image]

[image]

The user only submitted 1 form, but the form registered 3 responses. This random glitch has never happened before except for yesterday on 6/12/2020 and I can not find anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t

Comment: @Cooper No, and in fact my previous question similar to that one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275601/onformsubmit-trigger-occurs-twice-randomly-about-every-few-weeks?noredirect=1#comment110145665_62275601 has yet to be answered

Comment: Perhaps you need to submit is as an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)

Comment: Thank you, I just did. But I have very little hope they'll get back to me within a few months.

Comment: Yes, all the responses were not null values

Comment: Is the spreadsheet data added because it's linked to the Form, or your own code, from a Form Submit event trigger?  Have you shared the Form file from Drive, or added a collaborator to the Form?

Comment: @AlanWells The spreadsheet data is added because it's linked to the form. So it is most definitely a Google issue, as those responses were added to the form responses too. The Form sharing settings were not changed.

Comment: I'm interested in the issue that you created.  I'd like to keep track of the status.  Please provide the link.

Comment: @AlanWells No problem. Here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158891019

Comment: Thank you.  I have "stared" it.  You can click the star at the top, to the left of the title to increase the count.

Comment: Have starred my two recent ones. Thank you.