# onEdit trigger does not work for form edits, is there an alternative?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to update another google sheet (not the one the form adds info to) when google form is submitted. I tried this with onEdit() but found out that it does not trigger for form edits.

Is there an alternative that triggers on manual edit AND form edit for google sheets?

Comment: You can read about the onFormSubmit event object [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t) in the event that you have any problems with unwanted triggers.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your function to happen from both form submits and regular edits, add a function

```
onSubmit(){
   onEdit();
}
```