# How to send emails automatically from google sheets list

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list of customer names and email addresses that are being updated by a Google form.

I'm wondering if it's possible if every time a new customer is recorded, they are automatically sent a welcome email, without running the script every time.

I have "Name" in column "a", and "Email address" in column "B"

I have this simple code that I found, but it only sends to the last row when I run the script.

```
function activeRowEmail() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() ;

  var name = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();

  var email = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,"new email","hello " + name + ", thank you..... " );
}
```

Comment: Does every form submission create a new customer?

Comment: You only want it to go to the last row because that will always be the person who just filled out the form, right?

Comment: I would use an onFormSubmit trigger and get the data from e.values.  So it would be something like this: `function activeRowEmail(e) {
  var body=Utilities.formatString('Hello %s, thank you....',e.values[1]);
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.values[2],"New Email",body ); 
}` where I assumed that there is a timestamp in e.values[0]

Comment: J.g yeah that right

Comment: thanks cooper, im new in google script so if you can explain me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create onFormSubmit trigger for activeRowEmail() in spreadsheet
2. Using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) find the e.values indexes for mail and name.  I assumed that they were 2 and 1 because normally there is a timestamp in the first column of a linked sheet.

```
    function activeRowEmail(e) { 
      var body=Utilities.formatString('Hello %s, thank you....',e.values[1]); 
      MailApp.sendEmail(e.values[2],"New Email",body ); 
    }
```

Comment: thank you, actually i didnt change my code, i just crate a trigger..
i didnt knew about the trigger option.
thanks again.

Comment: If you get a lot of form submissions very quickly you may have problems with getLastRow() that is why I like using the data from the event object.  It is also possible to get spurious triggers and you can eliminate them with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56388938/7215091) which requires the use of the event object.