# Google Apps Script trigger function runs twice

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have the following trigger `setTrigger()` set for when a Google Form is submitted. For testing purposes I created a simple function `triggerFunction()` that creates a .txt file in my Google Drive.

```
function setTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('triggerFunction')
  .forForm("formId")
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function triggerFunction() {
  let folderId = [folderId];
  let blob = ['This is my blob'];
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile('file.txt',blob);
}
```

Now when I run the `triggerFunction()` manually it acts normally. It creates a file.txt in my folder. But when I submit a form on my Google form with `formId` it creates two separate `file.txt` files! How do I keep the trigger from running the function twice?!

I have tried the following but it still runs the function twice.

```
function setTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "triggerFunction").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('triggerFunction').forForm("formId").onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one trigger?  Look in the triggers page.  A few years ago we had a time when we were getting spurious additional triggers.  Perhaps they have returned but this is the first I've seen of it recently

Comment: No that's the only trigger I have.

Comment: Well perhaps you are actually getting a spurious trigger.  Here's a description of the last time I remember seeing a similar thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834837/how-can-i-be-getting-multiple-unwanted-event-blocks-from-the-same-onformsubmit-t/54860085#54860085